# Code doesn't execute

Tags: java

I have this piece of code

```
// If we click on an unfolded card
if (card.clicked == false) {
    clicksCount++;
    clickedCards[clicksCount - 1] = card;

    card.showCardImage();

    if (clicksCount == 2) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        // Loop through clicked cards and if they don't have the
        // same ID fold them
        if (clickedCards[0].cardID != clickedCards[1].cardID) {

            for (int k = 0; k < clickedCards.length; k++) {
                clickedCards[k].setDefaultIcon();
                clickedCards[k].clicked = false;
            }

            failedAttempts.setText("Failed Attempts: "
                    + ++failedCount);
        }

        attemptsCount++;
        attempts.setText("Attempts " + attemptsCount);
        clicksCount = 0; // reset click counter

    }
}
```

It's function for my pexeso game. The first card shows card's image fine, but when I click for the second time it doesn't show image of it. It only waits and then fold the first card.

I know that it is because of sleeping the thread but don't know what should I do.

I'll be glad for any idea or advice.

Comment: what is `card` (my crystal ball is asking if `cardID` a String)

Comment: Also you might want to use a debugger and figure out by yourself (or narrow down the issue)

Comment: @RC.: A debugger, while usually useful, would not help here, since the program's logic would work just fine, but the the cause of the problem, the `Thread.sleep(...)` freezing the Swing event dispatch thread (EDT) and thus freezing Swing graphics, would be something that would be very hard to isolate with a standard debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this is a Swing GUI (you never tell us). If so, then you're right: calling `Thread.sleep(...)` on the Swing event thread will put the entire GUI to sleep, including all GUI drawing. Instead use a Swing Timer set to a delay of 1000 ms. In your Timer's ActionListener, you will change the card back to the original. You will tell the timer not to repeat via a setter method, `setRepeats(false)`.

The [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what I wanted to know :) and for next time I'll tell which gui it is :D